# IntelliSense: значение типа "Massiv1 *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "Massiv2 *"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class Massiv1 {
protected:
 float *A;
 int n;
public:
 Massiv1();
 ~Massiv1();
 void EnterParam();
 void DisplayParam();
 void Product();
};
class Massiv2: public Massiv1 {
 public:
  Massiv2();
  ~Massiv2();
  void LoadFromFile();
}; 
int main() {
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
 Massiv1 massiv1;
 Massiv2 massiv2;
 Massiv2 *mass;
 int key1;
  cout << "|--\t Main Menu\t--|" << endl;
  cout << "1 - Obicnuy massiv" << endl;
  cout << "2 - iz faula" << endl;
  cout << "ESC - exit" << endl;
  key1 = getch();
  switch(key1) {
   default: system("cls"); cout << "---------------" << endl << "Error! Wrong tags" << endl << "---------------" << endl; break;
   case '1': system("cls"); mass = &massiv1; break; // Тут ошибка
   case '2': system("cls"); mass = &massiv2; break;
  }     
 system("pause");
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: @pavel задача: Создать базовый класс «массив1», описав в нем функции ввода массива с клавиатуры, вывода его на экран и нахождения произведения

элементов массива. Породить от него класс «массив2», переопределив в нем функцию ввода массива таким образом, чтобы значения элементов массива загружались из файла.

Comment: mass объявите как Massiv1. Но тут методы странно названы. По логике использовать виртуальные методы надо.

Comment: @pavel А зачем использовать virtual void, если эти методы не переопределяются в классе-потомке?

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на фрагмент:

```
Massiv1 massiv1;
Massiv2 massiv2;
Massiv2 *mass; 
//...
```

И после этого вспомнинайте, что можно присвоить указателью родительского класса  адрес обьекта(указатель) производного класса, но нельзя наоборот. Поэтому:

```
case '1': system("cls"); mass = &massiv1; break;
```

является ошибкой, так как  `mass`(указатель на Massiv2) не  может содержать адрес обьекта типа `Massiv1`